# Not integers values for line width in R

Tags: r, plot, width

I am trying to make plots using not integers values for lwd. However, I have realised that, using values such as 1.5 or 0.5, gives me the same plot as using lwd=1.

How can I adjust the line width to intermediate values?

Answer (score 1):

If you check `?par` it says that lwd represents:

> The line width, a positive number, defaulting to 1. The interpretation is device-specific, and some devices do not implement line widths less than one. (See the help on the device for details of the interpretation.)

So for example if you are outputting the plot to pdf check `?pdf` and see that line width is interpreted as multiples of 1/96th of an inch and that 1 is the minimum. It is not possible then to make use of a "0.5" linewidth.

Consider what you are trying to show in your plot and perhaps scale the values up to a range of integers that make sense.